# need to add pushviewcontroller in view based application

Tags: iphone

```
 -(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"welcome button");
    testWebView = [[[TestWebView alloc]init] autorelease];
    [self presentModalViewController:testWebView animated:YES];

    [testWebView test];
}
```

i trigger the buttonclicked and there i need to do PushViewController.

My application is view based application

@All

Thanks in advance./

Comment: testWebView is inherited from uiview or uiviewcontroller?

Comment: testwebview is from uiviewcontroller

Comment: So you want to switch from view-based application to navigation-based application?

Answer (score 3):

You will need a navigation controller to perform the push operation. Go through the reference document on [`UINavigationcontroller`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and this sample [tutorial](http://cocoadevblog.com/uinavigationcontroller-customization-tutorial) should get you started

Answer (score 0):

Add a navigation controller in the app delegate and perform push operation through that navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

testWebView *srwmvc =[[testWebView alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:srwmvc animated:TRUE]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your view's `UIViewController` to access the navigation Controller

eg.

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
testWebView *testWebView =[[testWebView alloc]init];
[myViewUIController.navigationController pushViewController:testWebView animated:TRUE];
}
```